# p5.js cannot read random values of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, p5.js

**Hello!**

I'm trying to make something in p5.js, and the program gets stuck when it tries to get a random value of array. Here is a simple program I made to demonstrate:

```
var arr = [100, 200];
var a;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  a = random(0, 1);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  ellipse(arr[a], 20, 20, 20);
}
```

The program returns a message saying that the ellipse function wanted a number, but got a variable. It works if say `arr[0]` or `arr[1]`, but not `arr[a]`.

I'm using the p5.js Web Editor. I have no idea why this is happening. If you have a solution, please respond. Thanks!

Comment: random function returns a float number

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an easier way to get a random element of an array with P5.js.
`a = random(arr);` will return a random element from the array.

Comment: Oh nice, I didn't see that feature in the docs until just now. Much easier than my answer!

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/random), the `random()` function will:

> Return a random floating-point number.

This means it could be something like **0.123**, which is clearly *not* an array index.

If you want a random index from the array, you should do something like:

```js
var arr = [100, 200];
var a = Math.round(random(0, arr.length));
```

This lets you be able to add more items to your source array without needing to adjust any other code. And then it rounds it to the nearest integer (up or down) depending on the floating point value.

Answer (score 0):

P5.js Random returns a  random floating-point number. [Documentation](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/random)

Working demo:

```js
var arr = [100, 200];
var a;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  a = Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  ellipse(arr[a], 20, 20, 20);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@0.10.2/lib/p5.js"></script>
```